# How to get carrier signal after returning from international travel

Tags: sim

So I’m sitting here connected to WiFi in the Houston airport on a long layover, returning from my trip to Mexico. The top left of my phone says “No Service”. I’ve chatted with my Carrier (Sprint) about 5 times and they eventually told me that some iPhones “get stuck” in the country they travelled to and that I need to stop in to a Sprint store to get a new SIM card. That just seems insane to me and I’m sitting here trying futilely to figure out how to connect, so I thought I would post here to see if anyone else has figured out a solution.

I have tried:

- about a dozen service updates (##UPDATE#) - every attempt fails, even those after multiple attempts by sprint to update my settings remotely
- a handful of reboots
- turning on data roaming
- turning off data roaming
- reset network settings
- some other ## number I found for resetting carrier settings

My wife has the same iPhone 6s and hers is working fine.  I imagine the difference is that when we got to Mexico, I could not send SMS messages to my wife. I’d had data roaming disabled (which I did a long time ago when I lived near Canada and had a huge bill for frequently roaming on a Canadian tower.) When I tried to text my wife while in Mexico, I was getting an error about iMessage needing to be enabled in order to send the message (even though it was enabled). Eventually, they told me that data roaming in Mexico was included in my plan, so I turned it back on and that seemed to work around the SMS issue.

Now that I’m back in the US however, it seems I cannot connect to any Sprint towers at all. I’ll go to the sprint store tomorrow I guess, but it seems like there’s got to be a way to reconnect without new hardware.

Comment: Is there an option for Network Selection in cellular settings, or is it just in my country ?

Comment: You know, I only know where that setting should be because I used it in Mexico when trying to solve the SMS issue. That settings page appears to no longer be present.

Comment: I took the phone to a corporate sprint location today and they installed a new SIM card. And... it didn’t work. They suggested I go to another sprint store located 20 minutes away in PA where there was a technician on duty who could replace the SIM card reader. Instead, I opted to restore the phone, which a rep on the phone had suggested if the new SIM card didn’t fix it. The restore worked. Still, it seems crazy that that’s necessary.

Comment: that does make for an answer. Also, I hope you had backup.